# Inserting variable into a query

Tags: mysql, sql, input, prepared-statement

I'm aware of prepared statements, but my question is a bit different.

Let's pretend we have the following situation, where the variable `$table` **does not** come from external sources, i.e. it is simply **a string variable hardcoded into the script**.

```
if($i == 1)
    $table = "students";
else if($i == 2)
    $table = "lecturers";

$sql = "select * from ".$table." where attending = 1";
$db->exec($sql);
//etc
```

**My question**: is it safe to include the `$table` variable into the query like in the above example? To my knowledge, we should only use prepared statements for user input data, right? If not, please correct me.

Comment: A) it shouldn't be a problem, B) use prepared statements anyway

Comment: You can use prepared statements any time you want to put strings together to form a query.  For instance, they are needed for dynamically pivoting data, where there is no data input.

Comment: @ElendilTheTall I was trying to think of a way to say the same thing - in theory you're safe. Don't take the risk!

Comment: I'm using the ADO DB abstraction layer and when I do this ($db->Execute("select * from ? where attending =1",$table), the result I get is select * from 'students' where attending =1 (note the '). This breaks the query.

Comment: Having a variable table name is usually indicative of a schema that violates the [Principle of Orthogonal Design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_Orthogonal_Design).

Comment: I wonder how could I be violating the principle mentioned above by having two separate tables - one for students and one for lecturers? In my opinion, the less clutter, the better (as opposed to having one big table for both students and lecturers).

Comment: What you see it as "less clutter", the RDBMS sees as difficult to organise.

Comment: I really can't agree that it would be more semantic to stuff all that data into one table, instead of separating students from lecturers. The opposite seems stupid to me, even though I do understand the aforementioned principle. Some principles sacrifice convenience for code clarity. The POD one does neither.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't receive the content of the variable from the user, you're safe from SQL Injection. However, you could use a prepared statement for efficiency reasons. This way, the statement is parsed only once, and not every time it's executed. For more information, read this:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html